# Using Index Match Function in VBA to find additional data from tables on different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 6 tables one on each sheet from A1:O27... I am trying to use Index and Match to get data from these tables; the name (A1:O1) and the user input value (A2:O27). I have gotten this to work on a normal excel spreadsheet but it is very sloppy. I wanted to make an overall function to do the searching for me. The goal is to search for the name first, get the column value and then find the row corresponding to the user's input value. With the known row I then need to index to the second to last column to get the corresponding value as the output to the function. How do I go about having the sheet change based off of the user input if the dimensions and layout are all the same for each table. Also would this need to be put into a loop to search for the correct location or can I just use the Index/Match functions? Here is what I have so far:

```
Function findSPL(Sonar As String, Distance As String, Condition As String) As String

Dim sonarcol As Range
Dim Dis As Range
Dim c2 As Integer
Dim r2 As Integer

'Set sonarcol to be equal to the "headers"'
'Set Dis to be equal to the table's data'
'Condition is equal to the selected table from drop down list user selects'

Set sonarcol = Worksheets(Condition).Range("A1:O1")
Set Dis = Worksheets(Condition).Range("A2:O27")

'First find the Column value that has the Sonar's name (Exact)'
'Using the column value in c2, find the row that has the user input distance'

c2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sonar, sonarcol, 0)
r2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Dis, WorksheetFunction.Match(Distance, Dis, 1), c2)



'Use the row value from r2 to find the SPL value from column 14 row r2'
findSPL = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Dis, r2, 14)


End Function
```

The image is showing one of the tables used and what I am trying to do. (find the column number then the corresponding row number... from that row number find the SPL value in column N (14) = 185

[image]

Comment: `but it is very sloppy` - why? It is a straightforward formula, no need to involve VBA. `index($N$2:$N$27, match(user_input, index($A$2:$O$27,,match(sonar, $A$1:$O$1, 0)), 0))`.

Comment: @GSerg This is my first time really using Excel at all and it was sloppy for me because I have 3 user inputs, 1 decides which table i use, the sonar name, and the value we are searching for... I had it in a bunch of IF statements to look through a table and then used index match to find the SPL ... aka I am trying to follow along. I will give that a go though!